# Android: Relative layout, change X coord

Tags: android

I have an Activity with relative layout on whole screen. In left top corner I have button. And on button click I want move layout from 0 X coord to 100 X coord. I tried something like this in onclick method:

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            param.leftMargin = 100;
            meRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(param);
```

But this thing just made my relative layout width smaller, its change left margine and thats it, but I don't want to change layout width, just want to change X coord, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me your code seems to be perfect, only the matter is of `FILL_PARENT`. As you used `FILL_PARENT` then the *system will assign the space left in the display(less margin)* thats why you layout became small, So Try this.

```
int width= mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( width, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            param.leftMargin = 100;
            meRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Comment: I tried width 300, but thats not work...Still width become smaller

Comment: so looks like layout cannot be moved outside the main window ?

Comment: take a `HorizontalScrollView` as parent in your layout.xml and you will get to know

Comment: well in HorizontalScrollView that works fine, how they do that ? )

Comment: without HorizontalScrollview, implementations is still correct but the thing is to show the content outside the display boundary you must have to take Scroll control.